# CDI Ambigious Dependency Injection with Producer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have one jar, where a Logger is produced:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {
    @Produces
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

The jar is referenced as dependency via maven in a second jar. In the second I have classes which `@Inject` the Logger. For some classes the injection seems to be fine, but for others eclipse shows a warning:

> No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-346 §5.2.2]

An example for a class where the warning shows up:

```
@Named("errorHome")
@SessionScoped
public class ErrorHome implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    Logger log;
    ...
}
```

but not in

```
public abstract class ListAbstraction<T> extends ListController<T> {
    @Inject
    Logger log;
    ...
}
```

The `beans.xml` is present in both jars. 
Why do I get the ambigious injection warning?

**UPDATE**

The warning only shows up in classes with CDI annotations. Might it be a problem of different scopes?

*(I have removed the second example, where the warning was showing up, because I have copied the wrong code. In that class was no warning.)*

Comment: Are you sure it is about the same `Logger`? There are classes with this name in various packages, you may be producing a (say) `org.slf4j.Logger`, but the bean actually wants a `java.util.logging.Logger`. Can you double-check?

Comment: Unfortunately it is everywhere the same import: `org.slf4j.Logger`.

Comment: Just noticed: you say "Eclipse shows a warning". Is it an eclipse warning, or a warning from the application itself, i.e. is it a yellow marker within Eclipse, or does the application server display it in the logs? If it is a marker within Eclipse, I would ignore it (or try a clean-and-build cycle, or deactivate CDI validations).

Comment: Updated my question with further observations. The logging in application server does not work for the classes where the warning is shown. In the other classes logging works as expected.